# UISlider setThumbTintColor with [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:] makes thumb transparent on highlight

Tags: uislider, uicolor

I tried to make the thumb on my UISliders have a brushed metal look using setThumbTintColor and using UIColor's colorWithPatternImage but when I start to scrub with it the thumb becomes mostly transparent. I've tried many things but havent found anything that helps. Has anyone else ran into this type of problem?

UISlider normal image:

[image: UISlider normal image]

UISlider highlighted image:

[image: UISlider highlighted image]

Comment: @pad Thanks for adding the images, I couldn't because my rank is too low as a new user.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround on this one. Put this one in my viewDidLoad.

```
[mySlider setThumbImage:[mySlider currentThumbImage] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```